# AngularJS - Mapping a date from a range of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that in the header, produces 12 cells start with the current date, then subtracting one month, so:

```
22 Oct 2014   |   22 Sep 2014   |   22 Aug 2014 etc etc
```

I then have a JSON file with a list of dates. I have an ANgular service that retrieves the dates however, what i am then trying to do, compare the range of dates in the header, then counts how many items from my JSON, fall in between the dates.

Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8nCKlxRAdtosc0EN2swG?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th ng-repeat="months in getMonths track by $index">{{ months }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td ng-repeat="months in getMonths track by $index">
                <span ng-repeat="item in filtered = (DateMapping(months))"></span>
                <p>{{filtered.length}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

So, the output would look something like:

```
22 Oct 2014   |   22 Sep 2014   |   22 Aug 2014 etc etc
    2         |       5         |       0       etc etc
```

---

UPDATE:

```
 $scope.DateMapping = function(months) {

        var curDate = new Date(months);
        var prevDate = new Date(months);
        prevDate = new Date(new Date(prevDate.setMonth(prevDate.getMonth() - 1)).setDate(prevDate.getDate() - 1));

        //console.log("curDate:  " + curDate);
        //console.log("prevDate: " + prevDate);

        var jsonEntries = $scope.Dates;

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonEntries.length; i++) {
            var jsonDate = jsonEntries[i].Date.substring(6, jsonEntries[i].Date.length - 2);

                if (jsonDate >= curDate && jsonDate <= prevDate ) {
                    //PERFORM .push
                }
                else {

                }
        }
    };
```

Comment: if the date is `01 Oct 2014` which cell it should be added... in 22 Oct or 22 Sep

Comment: @ArunPJohny - The 22 Oct

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks like a simple groupBy with a custom grouping function on that data should work.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Essentially for any given date, e.g. 01 Oct 2014, it should search to be between 22 Oct and 21 Sep, if fail, then search 22 Sep 21 Aug.. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv - i tried a groupBy by passing in {{months}}, but didnt seem to work.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv - Updated code with function

Comment: @ArunPJohny - updated question with function.

Comment: what about http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7o52rz6L/4/ ?